# Using "%s" in python with str() and in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm writing this code

```
for n in filtered_list:
    for a in range(1,3):
        duplicate = str(filenameRegex.group(1) + "(" + n + ")" + filenameRegex.group(2))
```

I've been wondering is there a more concise way to write this? I mean the "(" + n + ")" part. I was thinking about something like `%s s = n`, but I don't know and couldn't trial-and-error how to use it in this case.

Comment: Python 3 has [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you have to use `%d` instead of `%s` because n is an integer, not a string !

```py
for n in filtered_list:
    for a in range(1, 3):
        duplicate = "%s(%d)%s" % (filenameRegex.group(1), n, filenameRegex.group(2))
```

This is old-school formatting, though. In Python 3 you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
for n in filtered_list:
    for a in range(1, 3):
        duplicate = f"{filenameRegex.group(1)}({n}){filenameRegex.group(2)}"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this:

```
duplicate = "%s(%s)%s"%(filenameRegex.group(1),n,filenameRegex.group(2))
```

or

```
duplicate = "{0}({1}){2}".format(filenameRegex.group(1),n,filenameRegex.group(2))
```